# Questions about the Space of Matrix Coefficients

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Apologies in advance for the basic question: In reading up on representation theory, I came across a confusing definition for the $M(\rho)$, the space of matrix coefficients of a representation $(G, \rho, E)$:

Let $\rho_{ij}(s)$ be a matrix representation of $\rho(s)$ in some basis for $E$. Then $
\rho_{ij}$ is a function $G \to \mathbb k$ (the underlying field). Let $M(\rho) = \mbox{span} \{\rho_{ij} : i,j=1,...,\dim E\}$.

My confusion lies in the disappearance of $s$ from above; are we to take the span of the matrix coefficients from $\rho_{ij}(s)$ for *all* $s \in G$? I assume so, since that's the only thing that really makes sense, but I wanted to check.

In addition, after showing that this definition is basis-independent and showing how $M(\rho)$ can be viewed as a $G \times G$-module, it is stated that if $\rho, \rho'$ are two non-equivalent representations, then $M(\rho)$ and $M(\rho')$ are linearly independent, since they afford two non-equivalent representations of $G \times G$. Is there a good intuition for why this is true?

Comment: the span is taken as a subset of the functions from $G$ to $k$. the elements $\rho_{ij}(s)$ live in $k$, so they will have a very dull span

Comment: I only answered the first part of your question (so far) because I don't know what you mean by "$M(\rho)$ and $M(\rho')$ are linearly independent"; they're subspaces, not vectors. Out of interest (and because it might be useful), what were you reading? Neither of the representation theory books on my desk have an index entry for matrix coefficients.

Comment: Yeah, I was unclear about what that meant as well- maybe I should interpet it as meaning they're disjoint? I'm reading these notes: http://www.mccme.ru/~panyush/lecturesRT.pdf, and this material comes up on page 10. And thanks for your answer to the first part!

Comment: i think it's more natural to think of the second part as the converse of "isomorphic representations define the same space of matrix coefficients"

Comment: It seems to mean $M(\rho)\cap M(\rho')=\{0\}$; this is used in the conclusion that $\mathbb{k}[G]\cong\bigoplus_\rho M(\rho)$. I don't really see why it's true yet though - I'll get back to you if I figure it out.

Comment: It also occurs to me that because my partial answer has been upvoted, this question no longer appears on the unanswered list. It might be useful (perhaps after some time has passed, in case you get more responses anyway) to edit your second question out, and post it as a new separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The disappearance of $s$ is due to the sentence "then $\rho_{ij}$ is a function $G\to\mathbb{k}$". The function $\rho_{ij}$ acts on $G$ by taking an element $s\in G$ to the $(i,j)$-th entry of the matrix $\rho(s)$ in the chosen basis for $E$. The $\rho_{ij}$ are thus elements of the vector space $(\mathbb{k}G)^*$, the $*$ denoting dual, and it makes sense to take their span.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. One question I have remaining then is that the notes claim that the elements $\rho_{ij}$ (and thus also $M(\rho)$ ) lie inside $\mathbb k [G]$, not its dual. Is this just wrong?

Edit 2: Unless he's just identifying $\mathbb k [G]$ with its dual since it's finite dimensional maybe?

Comment: Strictly, yes. But they are isomorphic vector spaces, and $\mathbb{k}G$ comes with a "special" basis (i.e. $G$), so you could transfer $\rho_{ij}$ into $\mathbb{k}G$ using the isomorphism that pairs each $g\in G$ with its dual.

Comment: OP confusion in this comment comes from the notation.  It is traditional to use $\mathbb{k}[G]$ to denote the space of $k$-valued function on $G$, this is not strictly the same thing as the group algebra $\mathbb{k}G$, although in finite group case you can identify the two spaces as duals, as you mentioned.  The material you are presenting does not only work for finite group $G$; it is the main tool for studying (certain representations of) $GL_n(K)$ for $K$ infinite, and groups of such like.  (See Green's book Polynomial Representations of $GL_n$)

Comment: @Aaron OK, that's good to know - I'm not familiar with the $\mathbb{k}[G]$ notation and just assumed it was a variant on $\mathbb{k}G$.